# How to identify the wall type and studs for drilling

Tags: drywall, walls, drill, masonry

I need to anchor an Ikea bookcase and a drawer to the wall, but despite days of Internet research I am not able to identify where I can drill a hole in my wall. I have tried knocking on the wall to listen to the ‘depth’ of the sound to distinguish masonry from drywall. I think the wall onto which I am planning anchor the furniture is a drywall based on the hollow sound upon knocking. Now I am trying to identify the studs within the wall, but the sound method is not helping as every knock sounds the same. I bought a stud finder to no avail as it is not giving me reproducible results and it’s not identify studs in a periodic pattern which makes me think that there is something wrong with it (or the way I use it). I found the hole in the picture. I am wondering if it is possible to identify the wall type from the picture of this hole (whether it is masonry or drywall). [image]

I’d be very grateful if someone can guide me on how to identify where I can drill a hole in the wall to attach somewhat heavy furniture like a wardrobe or a bookcase.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Looks to me like concrete (or masonry) all the way through. Is that light on the other side?

Comment: It is light indeed. It’s a hole from one room to the other. I guess it’s concrete all the way. I was suspicious as the knocks sounded hollow.

Comment: How thick are the walls it could be block construction with a skim coat to make the wall smooth.  How thick is the wall?  Interior walls are not normally poured unless load bearing in the US because of cost.

Comment: Fyi, you don't need to anchor to a stud. It doesn't really matter how heavy the items are, you are just keeping them from falling over, the loads will not be significant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If drywall, look for drywall screw holes. Typically, the screws are drilled into studs for better anchoring.
Try a magnet to expose screw heads.